# Geopandas: AttributeError: 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'run_callable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, sqlalchemy, geopandas

I need help with this error, AttributeError: 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'run_callable'

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


def insert(df):
    calidades_df = df.copy()
    calidades_df.insert(loc=0, column='proceso', value=p['proceso'])
    calidades_df.insert(
        loc=len(calidades_df.columns),
        column='baja',
        value=False)

    engine = create_engine(
        "postgres://usr:pass#@localhost:5432/database"
    )
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        calidades_df.to_postgis(
            'calidades',
            conn,
            schema='ndvi',
            if_exists='append',
            index=False
            )
```

The error occurs only when using geopandas dataframe with the to_postgis() function. With pandas dataframes using the to_sql() function works fine. Thanks in advance

Comment: p is a dictionary that comes in the parameters

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.
Please provide more information about what you want to do and achieve, also the information at which line the error occurs is very helpful to others

Comment: Hi, the error occurs in calidades_df.to_postgis(). I want to upload the data to PostgreSQL/Postgis server using sqlalchemy connection with transacction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled accross the same problem and it seems the `to_postgis()` method is kind of broken. So what I did is implementing https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239231/36712 which uses the `to_sql()` from pandas. You just have to make your geometry into `WKT` and defining a dtype for the geometry column.